# Console error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : Learning sprites'

Tags: javascript, html, sprite, unexpected-token

This is my [code](https://gist.github.com/jfascetti/790c17bb4c77ce19fd9566f5af5b971d) (I am linking it because I do not know where the problem is and I do not want to link it all to this post). I am getting this error in the console: [image: (photo of error message)]  
The error is in line 57, but I do not know what is wrong.

```
rectangle = {
    height : 32,
    jumping : true,
    width : 32;
    x : 144,
    x_velocity : 0,
    y : 0,
    y_velocity : 0
};
```

Comment: Look at the error.  Then look **carefully** at the line that's generating it, and the answer will be obvious to you.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that. It's quite depressing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor syntax error that's causing your error. Update this line:

```
rectangle = {
                height : 32,
                jumping : true,
                width : 32, // Replace ; with ,
                x : 144,
                x_velocity : 0,
                y : 0,
                y_velocity : 0
            };
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :-)